# My user defined variable deletes all my other info when I try to display it with my other info

Tags: javascript, html

My code displays the variable value on a blank page and deletes my other data. I need to show it along with my other information.

This is my html code:

```
var num = 500;
var decrease = document.getElementById("sendingAmount");

            function TakeAway() {
                num -= sendingAmount.value;

                document.write(num);

            }
```

Comment: You need to place the result inside an HTML tag! This can be done by referencing the elementId.

Answer (score 1):

To change element text you can use `textContent`, e.g :

```
document.getElementById("sendingAmount").textContent = num;
```

Or add another element with id `result` and change his text.

**HTML :**

```
<span id='result'></span>
```

**JS :**

```
document.getElementById("result").textContent = num;
```

Hope this helps.